# Stochastic volatility and forward start contracts

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-volatility

Why is it more accurate to use stochastic volatility when pricing let's say a forward start option (*ie* an option priced today but striked in a future date) ?

Answer (score 1):

Local vol model gives a "too shallow" forward skew. Derivatives of which the price are depending on the forward skew will be mispriced. If i remember correctly, Hagan's paper